# How can I qualify a .NET type with assembly name for Visual Studio debugger to disambiguate while using an ambiguous type?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am using the VS debuggers 'Immediate Window' to call a static API on a class which is an ambiguous type defined in 2 different assemblies.

The call fails with the following message:
The type `foo` exists in both `blah.dll` and `bar.dll`

This message makes sense since this is indeed the case. My question is how can I work around this in the debugger to specify which assembly I want to be used for binding this type?

Is there a way to qualify a type with the assembly name that it is defined in?

Thanks
Bhavin.

Comment: are they in the same namespace ? Usually, different assemblies use different namespaces?

Comment: They are in the same namespace. This is unfortunate and I cannot change these assemblies.

Moreover, the code in the API is exactly the same so it doesn't matter which type the debugger chooses -- I just want it to use any one but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you have two types which have the same name and namespace but live in different assemblies?  If that is the case, unfortunately there is no way to disambiguate this call in the immediate window.  The immediate window considers both of these types to be in scope and since assembly name cannot be a part of the cast syntax in C# or VB.Net there is no way to disambiguate these types.

The only option you have is to create an alternate debug only API which binds to one or the other.  Then call this during the debugging session.

Comment: Does the same apply to the Watch window (in VS2010)? I found this answer of yours while looking for more information on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882391/how-to-disambiguate-type-in-watch-window-when-there-are-two-types-with-the-same), and it's sounding like the two situations are comparable.

Comment: @shambulator yes the same applies to the watch window.  The watch, immediate, locals and even hover tips are all views over the same underlying data engine.  If one can't differentiate then the others can't either

Comment: @JaredPar Does VS2012 handle this any better? E.g. it could let the user choose/prioritize a dll, search the dependency graph to find the right one (starting from the active stack frame), get help from the compiler as to which dll would've been used in code....

Comment: @johv as far as I know there is no change in VS2012 here.

Comment: Same behavior in VS2013 too.

Comment: not even using reflection to get a handle on the right type/method?

Answer (score 1):

As Maslow suggests, it is possible to use reflection to get what you want. It's not pretty, though. For example, if you want to see the value of the static property `My.Properties.Settings.Default`, then assuming that `MainWindow` is some other type in the assembly (e.g. `blah.dll`) that contains the value you want to debug, this expression will get you the value:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly
    .GetAssembly(typeof(MainWindow))
    .GetType("My.Properties.Settings")
    .GetProperty("Default")
    .GetValue(null)
```

In this example, `My.Properties.Settings` is a type that is defined in two different assemblies.

It's also possible to call methods etc. by using the appropriate tools from the `System.Reflection` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not live with solution by **jaredpar** You may want to take a look at this SO question: [How to disambiguate type in watch window when there are two types with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882391/how-to-disambiguate-type-in-watch-window-when-there-are-two-types-with-the-same)

This approach can also be taken for Immediate Window **with some limitation** though.
You are depending on where the debugger is currently stopped (think yellow arrow in left margin of editor) it seem it must be at a location where the alias has been used and are still in scope.

Example:

- Create ClassLibrary2
- Create ClassLibrary3
- Create ConsoleApplication1
- Add ClassLibrary2 as reference to ConsoleApplication1 and change the property Aliases from global to myAlias2
- Add ClassLibrary3 as reference to ConsoleApplication1 and change the property Aliases from global to myAlias3
- change the content of the following files:

Program.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    extern alias myAlias2;
    extern alias myAlias3;
    using myConsole2 = myAlias2::ClassLibrary.Console;
    using myConsole3 = myAlias3::ClassLibrary.Console;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { // from now on you can use <code>myAlias2::ClassLibrary.Console.Write("ABC")</code> in Immediate Window
            myConsole2.Write("ABC");
            Write3();
            // from now on you can use <code>myAlias2::ClassLibrary.Console.Write("ABC")</code> in Immediate Window
        }

        private static void Write3()
        { // in here you can use both aliases
            myConsole3.Write("ABC");
        }
    }
}
```

ClassLibrary2/Class1.cs:

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public static class Console
    {
        public static void Write(string text)
        { // in here You cannot use the aliases in Immediate Window
            System.Console.Write("===");
            System.Console.Write(text);
            System.Console.Write("===");
        }
    }
}
```

ClassLibrary3/Class1.cs:

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public static class Console
    {
        public static void Write(string text)
        { // in here You cannot use the aliases in Immediate Window
            System.Console.Write("---");
            System.Console.Write(text);
            System.Console.Write("---");
        }
    }
}
```

Tested in VS2015 Community Edition