# How to disambiguate type in watch window when there are two types with the same name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In the watch window, I'm trying to look at `TaskScheduler.Current`, but it shows me the following error:

```
The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler' exists in both 
'CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary' and 'System.Threading.dll'
```

This is true for my program since:

- This is a .NET 4.0 exe which uses the `TaskScheduler` out of mscorlib (CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary)
- A dll is brought in through late binding which references an old Reactive Extensions .NET 3.5  System.Threading.dll which also has `TaskScheduler` in the same namespace.

**Question:** What syntax can I use in the debugger to specify the dll of the `TaskScheduler` I want to inspect?

As an aside: I assume there is no issue (i.e. no undefined behavior) in terms of having these two identically named types being brought into the same executable, right?

Comment: Interesting problem! There shouldn't be any ambiguity; references to types are all qualified by containing assembly. But I don't know if there's any way to qualify references in the debugger...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this works through the watch window (but I don't see why it shouldn't, who knows) - but the way to disambiguate between two dll-s with same types is using `extern alias`.

That's the same thing as the `global::` - except that in this case you can use to specify dll aliases.

> You can use it by setting / defining alias yourself on the dll
>   reference (I think there is alias field there in the properties).

[two different DLL with same namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672920/two-different-dll-with-same-namespace/3672987#3672987)

I'm not sure if this entirely applies to your case, i.e. if you are able to do that, but you'll have to try it out in your own case.

**EDIT:** (based on the comments)

Given specifics - I tried it in my debugger. Since the other one is late-binding - compiler doesn't know about it (of course, as it wouldn't work).

So in your source code (.cs where you need to do the watch anyway) add at the top e.g.

```
using mysystem = global::System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler;
```

Then in the watch `mysystem.Current` (I'm basing it on my example)

Or...

```
using mytasks = global::System.Threading.Tasks;
```

and `mytasks.TaskScheduler` - doesn't matter really which one really.

**EDIT2:**
And for historical reasons - I kind of confirmed that code-editing is unavoidable.

1) remove `mscorlib` from the project - project, setting, build, advanced.

2) unload and edit project configuration manually - add the mscorlib reference (adding through VS is not allowed). Also another fix is required for WPF apps (out of scope here),

3) add aliases for mscorlib - you can add multiple ones, separate w/ `,`, that works fine,

4) add `extern alias <your alias>`,

from that point you can reference it in debugger - but there is not way of forgoing the manual `code editing`. Also extern alias is per 'building unit', i.e. file, so nothing global.

In short, that's the best we could do, IMHO.

---

And a confirmation from @JaredPar on this
[How can I qualify a .NET type with assembly name for Visual Studio debugger to disambiguate while using an ambiguous type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571958/how-can-i-qualify-a-net-type-with-assembly-name-for-visual-studio-debugger-to-d/1572988#1572988)

Comment: I don't have any `extern alias`. I directly reference mscorlib.  System.Threading.dll comes in through late binding. With that in mind,  it's not clear what your suggesting I type into the watch window to disambiguate.

Comment: try `global::` - you can do the following in the code at least `var current = global::System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.Current;`. I still have no idea if the other dll will interfere with that.

Comment: Ah, I see. okay, I tried `global::System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler`, but I get the same error message.  Which makes sense to me because they are both in the global namespace (since they weren't brought in via an `extern alias`)

Comment: ok, will get there :) - here is another one - I tried it in my debugger. Since the other one is late-binding - compiler doesn't know about it (of course, as it wouldn't work). So in your source code (.cs where you need to do the watch anyway) add at the top e.g. `using mysystem = global::System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler;`. Then in the watch `mysystem.Current` (I'm basing it on my example).

Comment: Or `using mytasks = global::System.Threading.Tasks;` and `mytasks.TaskScheduler` - doesn't matter really - that's matter of preference now.

Comment: That works, thanks!  +1 for a good work-around.  Unfortunately, it means (a) I have to temporarily modify code to do my debugging and (b) I have to have in my call-stack a source file that has a `using` like this.  This won't be possible, generally, when I don't have the luxury of changing the source.

Comment: I understand that - problem is w/ `mscorlib` which is silently added (we can exclude it, but not sure if that'd help) - it doesn't seem possible putting an `alias` on it - which is the key here. Otherwise compilers are pretty 'predictable animals' and there's always some way to do things you need.

Comment: @MattSmith I think working around it as detailed in this answer is the closest you're going to get. I found a [similar question about the Immediate window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571958/how-can-i-qualify-a-net-type-with-assembly-name-for-visual-studio-debugger-to-d/1572988?noredirect=1#comment22664215_1572988), and got a pretty definitive answer from JaredPar.

Comment: @shambulator - I had another go at it yesterday (edited in just now), and it confirms what we know - I just didn't think it was valuable to add (as there is no solution w/o editing)

Comment: @shambulator Thanks for linking in that other question, I hadn't found that. @ NSGaga, thanks for the additions.